# volume density stronger to the edges

Tags: materials, shaders, volumetrics

I am trying to to get a denser volume to the edges, than in the center of the object.
I tried to drive the density through a fresnel, but this does not seem to work, does anyone have other suggestions?

Edit:

1. Node Setup was fresnel > color ramp > principled volume (density)
2. picture of object
   [image]

Comment: Hello, could you please show some pictures of your object?

Comment: i did upload a picture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: thank you, this seems to work :)

Comment: glad i could help!